# How to show total cost of a list of items in table

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuex

For an examination I need to create pdf from a vue.js front end app.
My issue is with the front-end, I'm using Vue 3 and I need to display the total amount of all the items in the table I've made using bootstrap5.

Also I need to understand if I can align correctly the table head, columns and the footer. At the moment the result isn't the best.

Since a price can be something like `28,50`, is possible to preserve it during the calculation?

```js
// @ is an alias to /src
//import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue'


export default {
  name: 'Home',
  data() {
    return {
      elFattura: [],
      nome: null,
      cognome: null,
      piva: null,
      sdi: null,
      numeroFattura: null,
      dataEmissione: null,
      codiceArticolo: null,
      descArticolo: null,
      qta: null,
      iva: null,
      prezzo: null,
      importiInseriti: [],
      importoParziale: 0
    }
  },
  computed: {
    importoTotale() {
      if (this.importiInseriti.length > 0) {
        return this.importiInseriti.reduce((p, n) => {
          return Number(p) + Number(n);
        });
      } else {
        return this.importoParziale;
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {

  },
  methods: {
    addItem() {
      this.elFattura.push({
        codiceArticolo: this.codiceArticolo,
        descrizione: this.descArticolo,
        qta: this.qta,
        iva: this.iva,
        prezzo: this.prezzo
      });
      this.importoParziale = this.prezzo;
      this.importiInseriti.push(this.prezzo);
    },
    removeAmount(index) {
      this.elFattura = this.elFattura.filter((item, i) => {
        if (i != index) {
          this.importiInseriti.splice(index, 1);
          this.importoParziale = this.importiInseriti.reduce((a, b) => {
            return Number(a) + Number(b)
          });
          return item;
        }
      });

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <h4 class="text-start">AGGIUNGI ARTICOLI</h4>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="" v-model="codiceArticolo">
        <label for="floatingInput">Cod. Articolo</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
      <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="" v-model="qta">
        <label for="floatingPassword">Qtà</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Descrizione" v-model="descArticolo">
        <label for="floatingPassword">Descrizione</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
      <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="IVA" v-model="iva">
        <label for="floatingPassword">% IVA</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-md-2 col-lg-2">
      <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Prezzo" v-model="prezzo">
        <label for="floatingPassword">Prezzo</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-md-1 col-lg-1">
      <a class="btn btn-success" href="#" @click.prevent="addItem"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <!-- intestazione fattura -->
  <div class="card text-start">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p class="m-0"><small class="pe-2">RAGIONE SOCIALE:</small>{{ nome }} {{ cognome }}</p>
      <p class="m-0"><small class="pe-2">P.IVA:</small>{{ piva }}</p>
      <p class="m-0"><small class="pe-2">SDI:</small>{{ sdi }}</p>
      <hr>
      <p class="m-0 d-inline pe-3"><small class="pe-2">FATTURA:</small>{{ numeroFattura }}</p>
      <p class="m-0 d-inline ps-2"><small class="pe-2">DEL:</small>{{ dataEmissione }}</p>

    </div>
  </div>
  
  <table class="table table-responsive">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">COD. ARTICOLO</th>
        <th scope="row">QTÀ</th>
        <th scope="row">DESCRIZIONE</th>
        <th scope="row">% IVA</th>
        <th scope="row">PREZZO</th>
        <th scope="row" v-show="this.elFattura.length > 0" colspan="2">EDIT</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(item, index) in elFattura" :key="index">
        <th scope="row">{{ item.codiceArticolo }}</th>
        <td>{{ item.qta }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.descrizione }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.iva }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.prezzo }} €</td>
        <td class="">
          <a class="btn-link text-decoration-none text-danger" href="#" @click.prevent="removeAmount(index)"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr class="text-end">
        <th scope="row" colspan="12">TOTALE {{ importoTotale }} €</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"></div>
```

Comment: Hey, why don't you add a variable when u stock the total amount and load it in data(){}

Comment: I didn't tried yet, but can you show an example?